# Is it possible to hide processes from ps or top on modern day kernels?

Tags: kernel-modules

I'm looking for a way to build a kernel module that can hide processes from ps and top commands. The kernel I'm working with is **3.13.0**. I'm not sure what kind of kernel data structure I should be messing with. I'm not looking for a fully functioning rootkit that's untraceable or hard to detect, I just want to start out hiding a process that I hard code but eventually I want to be able to build a rootkit to hit all processes created over the duration of the loaded mod.

I began to strace the ps command and found something like this for the process I'm trying to hide:

```
stat64("/proc/11914", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
open("/proc/11914/stat", O_RDONLY)      = 6
read(6, "11914 (dummy) S 3184 11914 3184 "..., 1024) = 279
close(6)                                = 0
open("/proc/11914/status", O_RDONLY)    = 6
read(6, "Name:\tdummy\nState:\tS (sleeping)\n"..., 1024) = 807
close(6)
```

I see that it's trying to open from `/proc` so I tried to to hide `/proc/<pid>` folder. I managed to hijack the `ls` system call to not display this folder but it clearly that has not worked.

I'm not exactly sure what is next, I checked then `open()` system call found out if I tried to filter a string match for my process, that would be a pretty bad way.

Maybe in my kernel version, there is an easier structure to mess with. Since it's a modern kernel, my `task_struct` doesn't have `next_task` and `prev_task` that I read on webpages that could make doing this 'fairly easy'

Any advice?

Comment: Hide from whom? Linux already supports hiding process information from other users. Do you need something more?

Comment: @muru Hiding from anybody who use ps and top commands, can root see hidden process easily without a detector?

Comment: You are basically looking for a way for doing something a rootkit would do?